# VBA loses flow of control when button calls new window using user32 libraries

Tags: vba, user32

I am using VBA with user32 libraries to manipulate windows.  In the application I am making, when I click on a certain button for which I already have the handle, a new window appropriately pops up.  I need to then press a button on that new window.  But after the code clicks the first button, the code doesn't move forward anymore.

If I had originally initiated the code by pressing F8 to step through, then I can manually close the new window, manually reopen it, and then continue stepping through my code and it works just fine to finish the program.  If I initially pressed F5 to just run the program without ever having stepped through, then I still have to manually close the window and code just gets stuck after opening the new window so no progress is made.

How do I ensure that the program doesnt lose control after the button is clicked and the new window pops up?

```
     'assume the objects are declared already and the functions are correctly imported.
     printDialogWindow = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Print")
     preferencesButton = findwindowEx(printDialogWindow, 0&, "Button", "P&references")
     Call SendMessage(PreferencesButton, BY_CLICK, 0, ByVal 0&)
     'code stalls here
     printPreferencesWindow = FindWindow(vbNullString,"Printing Preferences")
```

Comment: When you say "after the code clicks the first button, the code doesn't move forward anymore", what do you mean? **Is the button in discussion clicked or not**? I mean do you see the necessary window popping up? If so, this process of showing takes some milliseconds and you need waiting te new window to expose its handle, using a loop. Something as `Do While printPreferencesWindow= CLngPtr(0)` followed by `printPreferencesWindow = FindWindow(vbNullString,"Printing Preferences")` , `DoEvents` and eventually  `Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")`  `Loop`.

Comment: When you are not sure that the way of finding the handle is correct, you may place a variable to be incremented some times (3 - 4) and exit the `Loop` with a message saying that the handle could not be found after x attempts... But you know it is OK, working when offering time for the window to expose its handle.

Comment: The button is clicked and the next window successfully pops up immediately.  My real code does have some do while loops in it for that purpose, but I took it out for the question to make it more readable.  I know the way of finding the handle is correct because when I use stepping through, the window is found after I manually close the window and manually reopen it and then resume stepping through.

Comment: Nothing is happening in Windows "immediately"... Between the moment of clicking and the one when the new window exposes its handle, at least some microseconds pass. But the API call **does not wait for the window to be shown**. The code jumps (really) immediately to the next code line, when the searched handle does  not exist, yet. I said "eventually", but in such a case you should only use `DoEvents` inside the loop. If you do not want using it, is your choice. But if you use it, you will have a pleasant surprise. You can almost instantly return the handle only for a window already open.

Comment: Here is the original code in my actual program for that portion:
while printPreferencesWindow = 0
printPreferencesWindow = FindWindow(vbNullString,"Printing Preferences")
DoEvents
Wend

Comment: And doesn't it work?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the solution I found in simple terms was to use the Win32 "PostMessage" function instead of the "SendMessage".  SendMessage will wait for a response before it returns control back to the calling program.  PostMessage puts the message in a queue and then gives control back to the calling program right away.  In my case, because there are no other messages in the queue for that window, it processes the message right away, so there are no issues.